# How to define a "Master Layout" in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, layout, controller, laravel-5.1, view

I'm starting to use Laravel 5.1 from 4.2 and I have a question about the definition of layouts in the controller.

In 4.2 I have this:

```
private $layout = 'layouts.master';

public function showWelcome()
{
    $this->layout->content =  View::make('home');
}
```

When the view is loaded, the "Home" view will appear in the `@yield('section')` of "master.blade.php" in the layouts folder.

I searched for how to use this in 5.1 and I see that the assignment of the layout.masters has been removed, but I can't see the new usage anywhere.

Now in 5.1 I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use View;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

How can I say to the `showWelcome()` function that it has to yield the content with the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5.1 you can extend master layout in blade files writing at the top **@extends('layouts.master')** .  [From Laravel 5.1 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

```
    <!-- Stored in resources/views/child.blade.php -->

    @extends('layouts.master')

    @section('title', 'Page Title')

    @section('sidebar')
        @parent

        <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
    @endsection

    @section('content')
        <p>This is my body content.</p>
    @endsection
```